Unity Find all Gameobjects with certaint maintag, not having to specify the subtag?
I´m making a simple Unity 2D Idle game rigth now with a lot of balls jumping around and making money. I am currently using subtags to declare them( For everyone who doesnt know that, you can make subtags, as exempel "Ball/Standart Ball"). Is there anyway to get all the source for the "ball" tag and return also "Ball/Standart Ball", "Ball/Strong Ball" and "Ball/Laser Ball" ?
I cant find anything on that topic and even subtags are so rarely talked about. Or is there a nother Way to source for all gameobjects containing "Ball" in there name. They are all children of an Object, but not all last children.
Rigth now I have to search every tag one for one and add them to a list if I reference them all.
Thanks in advance:)

So as mentioned just to clarify again: There isn't something like "subtags".
All Unity does if you call tags "Something/Something" it nicely groups them into nested dropdown menus (like for any other menus in the GUI).
This is a pure editor sided handy feature but on runtime all these tags are completely unrelated individual strings - or better said hashes (which is what Unity uses for performance reasons).
=> No there is no way to do what you want if using tags.

This said I wouldn't go string-based at all - neither use tags nor names.
Instead I would use a proper component on the ball and have proper sub-classes.
Then you can easily auto-register all instances and also group them by the type.
I would probably do something like e.g.
public abstract class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    // will contain all active instances
    private static readonly List<Ball> activeInstances = new ();

    // will also contain all active instances but grouped by their actual type
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Ball>> typeToInstances = new ();

    public static IReadOnlyList<Ball> ActiveInstances => activeInstances;

    public static bool TryGetInstances(Type type, out IReadOnlyList<Ball> result)
    {
        if (typeToInstances.TryGetValue(type, out var typeList))
        {
            result = typeList;
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool TryGetInstances<T>(out IReadOnlyList<T> result) where T : Ball
    {
        if (typeToInstances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var typeList))
        {
            result = typeList.Cast<T>().ToList();
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    // automatically add yourself to the activeInstances and typeToInstances when coming active
    protected void OnEnable()
    {
        activeInstances.Add(this);

        var type = this.GetType();

        if(!typeToInstances.TryGetValue(type, out var typeList))
        {
            typeList = new List<Ball>();
            typeToInstances[type] = typeList;
        }

        typeList.Add(this);
    }

    // automatically remove yourself from the collections when coming inactive
    protected void OnDisable()
    {
        activeInstances.Add(this);

        var type = this.GetType();

        if(typeToInstances.TryGetValue(type, out var typeList))
        {
            typeList.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}

Then you derive your types like e.g.
public class StandardBall : Ball
{

}

public class LaserBall : Ball
{

}

etc.

Each of these can have their own specific required values and behavior - which you probably already have anyway.
And finally you can from anywhere access all instances using
var allActiveBalls = Ball.ActiveInstances;

or specific type groups
if(Ball.TryGetInstances<LaserBall>(out var allLaserBalls))
{
    // note that with current implementation the lists can still be empty though

    ...
}

if(Ball.TryGetInstances(typeof(StandardBall), out var allStandardBalls)
{
    // if needed have to cast manually to actual type

    ...
}


But is there then a way to "find" all gameobjects with certained class?

@Moritz sure -> Object.FindObjectsByType .. but as said with above base component you wouldn't need it

Now i managed to make Type to System.Type, but now im getting an Error for "result = typeList.Cast().ToList();". I googled alot cause I have never sawn anything like that before, but I cant figure out whats wrong. Can anyone help me?

what kind of error? You probably just miss a using System.Linq; there

Yes I did, but I have now decided that I use a different system which is fairly similar to this one, thank you for the input.:)
